# Seeking a beginner's tutorial for ServiceStack/Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, servicestack

I want to learn how to use ServiceStack to selfhost mvc/razor applications. I have only basic konwledge about MVC. I've already compiled and tested ServiceStack sample - RazorRockstars. It works (both Windows and Linux/Mono).

My problem is that I don't understand how it really works. Is there any tutorial describing how to create project like this, step by step? I'm not looking for finished working project, instead I want simple tutorial, with explanation step by step how to create it from scratch.

I've searched for this but still I can't find any matching my criteria.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me where you are facing problem. Means which part you are not getting?

Answer (score 0):

[Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training) has a great ServiceStack course made by John Somnez

or you could read the [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki)

Comment: I found this: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/12/self-hosting-servicestack-serving.html but I need to have MVC model/controller and I need to use external controls, like MVC Devexpress db mvc grids. This simple tutorial works, but I still don't know how to do what I want... any help? I can run devexpress mvc samples succesfully, but still have no idea how to use this with ServiceStack. There is no Model/Controller, there is now ViewBag etc... Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I would seriously recommend reading the documentation or watching the pluralsight course from start to finish.  You need to understand what ServiceStack is and what it offers, before trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your reposnses. I'm not asking for full solution but could you tell me if ServiceStack can offer me this? If not, I rather should to look for somwhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how view API is working. If your question is specifically for how you can define view for your project. There are multiple options with Servicestack.

You can find that documentation [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/View-and-template-selection).

Please let me know if any further detail is required.